# I want to create a label that looks like a toast

Tags: android, label, toast

I like the transparent and rounded edge look of the toast in android 2.3 on my htc phone...Is there anyway I can create a custom UI component that looks like a toast but functions like a label?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a shape in XML and set the resource as the background of a TextView.  The using the shape you can set rounded corners and a semitransparent color as the fill of it.  Then you can just reference it as your background.

The XML would look something like this...

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#80000000" />
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FF313131" /> 
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp" 
            android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" /> 
    <corners android:radius="4dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Check out the developers guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)